# ZSTD-compressed data is corrupt. --System halted

Tags: boot, system-installation

When I try to boot Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. After selecting "ubuntu" from a list. It gives me
ZSTD-compressed data is corrupt.    --System halted_ (error). And it does not go any further.
I tried changing hard drives where I have Windows OS and that is also not working, maybe some other issue, I guess. Using Windows hard drive, it gives me an error of 0xc0000098 Kernel is missing or corrupt. I think maybe the problem is not related to any Ubuntu and Windows OS but with my CPU or any internal hardware or software idk for sure.
I've tried other kernels under "advance" option, that'll just reboot my pc and then same again. Also tried installing new Ubuntu using bootable USB, but no luck. That will take me to a screen where an underscore is blinking continuously and then give the same error mentioned above. How do I troubleshoot this?
Thanks in Advance!